# How to align vertically beamer titlegraphics?

Tags: beamer, graphics, vertical-alignment, titles

In a `beamer` presentation, I am using the following code to add logos on my title page:

```
\titlegraphic{
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{logo-lirmm.png}
  \hspace*{0.75cm}~%
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{logo-york.png}
  \hspace*{0.75cm}~%
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{logo-dc.png}
}
```

This code aligns vertically the three logos **at the bottom**. How can I center them vertically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `\parbox` around the images can help to centre them:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \parbox[c]{3cm}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}
    \hspace*{0.75cm}%
    \parbox[c]{2cm}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}
    \hspace*{0.75cm}%
    \parbox[c]{1cm}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set each graphic inside a box, which you can then measure the contents of. In that way you can raise/lower the boxes into position so they are vertically aligned:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

% Store logos inside boxes
\newsavebox{\logoA}
\newsavebox{\logoB}
\savebox{\logoA}{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-a}}
\savebox{\logoB}{\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{example-image-b}}

\titlegraphic{%
  \raisebox{.5\dimexpr\ht\logoB-\ht\logoA}{\usebox{\logoA}}% raise smaller logo into position
  \hspace*{5cm}%
  \usebox{\logoB}
}

\title{A title}
\author{An author}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```